# PHP/CF is returning some weird string when trying to get the IP

Tags: php, ip, cloudflare

Here is my code:

```
function get_ip() { 
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])){ 
return $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]; 
} 
else{ 
return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
} 
}
```

And it used to work fine up until this morning it is returning:

```
2602:306:cdaf:2da0:e132:a096:5eb:a342
```

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: It is returning IPv6 address instead of usual IPv4.

Comment: So you basically copied my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an IPV6 address rather than the usual IPV4 address.

Comment: Thanks, I guess CF automatically changed my ipv6 option to on without me knowing.